# Can someone check my solution for AP Calc Volume of a Solid question

Tags: calculus, solid-of-revolution

Let $R$ be the region in the first quadrant bounded by $y=1/x$, the horizontal line, $y=1$, and the vertical line $x=e$.

Region $R$ is the base of a solid. For this solid, each cross section perpendicular to the y-axis is a semicircle. Find the volume of the solid.

Can someone please check my solution?

$A(y)=$ area of cross section $=$ area of semi circle with radius $=\frac{1}{2}\pi r^2$

When we graph these equations we get something like this: [image]

The diameter of the semi circle is $e-\frac{1}{y}$

so the radius is $\frac{1}{2}(e-\frac{1}{y})$

Therefore the area is $A(y)=\frac{1}{2}\pi (\frac{1}{2}(e-\frac{1}{y}))^2 = \frac{\pi}{8}(e-\frac{1}{y})^2$

At $x=e$, $y=\frac{1}{e}$ and we are given that $y=1$ so we have $\frac{1}{e}\leq y \leq 1$

To find the volume, we have $V=\int_{a}^{b} A(y) dy$

Thus we have $V=\int_{1/e}^1 \frac{\pi}{8} (e-\frac{1}{y})^2 dy$

$V=\frac{\pi}{8}(e^2-2e-1)$

Comment: Everything looks right up to the final solving of the integral, which I can't check just now.

Comment: I have a little issue how you set up the radius. I think you should use the washer method. Use the integral for $\pi{r}^2$ separately on radius $e$ and then radius $1/y$.Essentially this boils down to 2 integrals. There is a difference between $(R2-R1)^2$ and $R2^2-R1^2$. You did the first but I think you need the last

Comment: Nothing in the exercise specifies that it is a solid of revolution or even half of a solid of revolution.

Comment: You should get $V=\frac{\pi}{8}(2e-1)$ after you use the difference of squares rather than the square of the difference and add in the volume for the interval $[1,1/e]$.

Comment: Sorry I am getting confused. are you saying that my integral for V is incorrect? beccause when I integrate to get the volume, I keep getting $\pi/8(e^2-2e-1)$ so I don't know what I'm doing wrong

Comment: A cross-section is a planar section. To construct a cross-section perpendicular on y-axis that results in a semi-circular corona, it means the axis of rotation is the y-axis.

Comment: Your working is absolutely correct.

Comment: @MathLover Upon reflection, I agree, and I have deleted my comment.  My problem is that I have low visualization skills, and I did not realize the full significance of the phrase: "For this solid, each cross section perpendicular to the y-axis is a semicircle." My carelessness for not making more of an effort to understand the OP's statement: "The diameter of the semi circle is $(e - 1/y)$ ".

Comment: I completely misunderstood the definition of R. Your work now appears to be flawless. Good work.

Comment: What you have done here with your edit is not right. Can you please reinstate the original question? You have removed all details from the question and changed the title to an extent that this does not even remain a question. This was a highly voted question with good working of yours and someone visiting this question would wonder what the question is and what the votes and comments are about.

Comment: Rolled edit back to the original question, which appears to be why this ended up in the Review queue as missing context.  If OP is still around: please do not vandalise questions!

Answer (score 1):

You have two mistakes. What you call diameter is actually the radius and what you call area is supposed to be a difference of squares while you wrote a square of a difference.

First the solid is like a half torus obtained by rotating the region R half turn around y-axis.

The volume is $\int_1^e{\pi\cdot x\cdot (1-\frac{1}{x})\cdot dx}$, where:

1. $\pi\cdot x$ is the semi-circular path described by the cross-section
2. $(1-\frac{1}{x})\cdot dx$ is the cross section

Numerically, the volume is $\pi\cdot\left[\frac{x^2}{2}-x\right ]_1^e=\frac{\pi}{2}\cdot(e-1)^2$

Comment: i don't understand why you have $\pi *x * (1-1/x)$. shouldn't it be $\pi/2*(1-1/x)^2$

Comment: First we need to agree on one thing: the problem is stated wrongly in respects of semi-circle. if you slice the resulting solid with a plane perpendicular on y-axis that also intersects the region between red, green and blue limits, the resulting shape is a circular corona (the area between two circles). In this understanding, then it becomes obvious that the axis of rotation is the y-axis. We need to agree on the axis of rotation first, because as I already mentioned, the problem is ambiguous to say the least.

Comment: If the intended axis of rotation is not the y-axis, then my answer is not correct. If you have missed anything from the original text of the problem, please let me know. Otherwise my solution takes into account y-axis as axis of revolution.

Comment: Now to answer your question. The resulting shape resembles a half torus, with the main difference that the x-y section is not a circle but the shape bordered by green, red blue. The volume is the sum of elementary volumes. The elementary volume is again a semblance of a half torus, where the elementary section iis mentioned at 2. In my answer and the radius from the elementary section to the y-axis is mentioned in 1.

Comment: $\pi\cdot x$ is the semicircle length while $(1-\frac{1}{x})\cdot dx$ is the elementary area. Look on your graph to understand the elementary area and the distance to y-axis which represents the elementary radius of rotation.